# PowerShell Invoke-RestMethod Pagination -FollowRelLink not working

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0

I am trying to get data from a REST API which has pagination. I have tried to use the `-FollowRelLink` option which is part of `Invoke-RestMethod` but the is not working. The API Below returns a maximum of 175 records.

**PowerShell:**

```bsh
$Scryfall_Set_Card_Data = Invoke-RestMethod "https://api.scryfall.com/cards/search?order=name&q=in%3AELD" -FollowRelLink
Write-Host $Scryfall_Set_Card_Data.data.Count -ForegroundColor Cyan
```

**Response:**

```
object  "list"
total_cards 285
has_more    true
next_page   "https://api.scryfall.com/cards/search?format=json&include_extras=false&include_multilingual=false&order=name&page=2&q=in%3Aeld&unique=cards"
data    […]
```

The `Write-Host...` outputs 175

Comment: Try adding parameter `MaximumFollowRelLink` with a number greater than one

Comment: I tried that and it still just returned the first page worth of data.